# Calculating total weight of MST using Prim's and a heap

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

Attempting to implement a method that builds a MST using prim's and a min heap (using priority queue) and returns the total weight of the MST.

My code seems to produce different results to what is expected, however, looking at my code it seems to be fundamentally correct and follows closely to other examples online.

```
       for (int v = 0; v < size; v++)    {
            key[v] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            pred[v] = null;
            visited[v] = false;
        }

        int s = 0;
        key[s] = 0;

        for (int v = 0; v < size; v++)  {
            minHeap.add(new T(v, key[v], pred[v]));
        }

        while (!minHeap.isEmpty())  {
            int u = minHeap.poll().vertex;
            for (int v = 0; v < size; v++)  {
                if (g.getWeight(u, v) > 0 && !visited[v])  {
                    if (g.getWeight(u, v) < key[v]) {
                        key[v] = g.getWeight(u, v);
                        pred[v] = u;
                        minHeap.add(new T(v, key[v], pred[u]));
                    }
                }
            }
            visited[u] = true;
        }


        int distance = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)  {
            distance += key[i];
            if (!visited[i])
                return -1;
        }
        return distance;
```

current input is an adjacency array:

```
5       16      5       8       19      9       8       1       5       8
16      10      19      7       7       5       15      4       7       18
5       19      1       7       1       20      12      15      9       2
8       7       7       14      11      18      13      5       11      14
19      7       1       11      0       15      10      17      0       8
9       5       20      18      15      0       11      20      10      7
8       15      12      13      10      11      8       14      20      20
1       4       15      5       17      20      14      12      0       8
5       7       9       11      0       10      20      0       5       7
8       18      2       14      8       7       20      8       7       15
```

expected output is: 36
current output is: 32

Comment: It would help if you added what output you are getting and the expected output that you want!

Comment: edited to show input and expected output vs current output

Comment: MST? merge sort tree?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your minHeap is sorting items to the largest key[v] rather than smallest. Maybe try

`minHeap.add(new T(v, Integer.MAXVALUE - key[v], pred[u]));`

Comment: hey, just checked. It's definitely sorting by lowest using a comparator, and that change gives another incorrect output

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in where the visited[u] = true statement was.

moving that statement to after polling for vertex with highest priority in minHeap and before the loop checking for adjacent vertices fixed it.